# Body text from file

Tags: powershell, outlook

A file that adds text to an e-mail if it has more than one sentence does not add any sentence correctly.

Content @ is empty.

It only adds a signature.

Input file (name: `Text_file.txt`):

```
email:m.kowalczyk@email.test.com
emialcc:
emailbcc:
Subject:2513000013
attachment:Y:\attachment\2513000013.pdf
```

Text file:

```
This is a test
This and other lines do not show up
test3
test4
test5
```

PowerShell script :

```
$destDir = "C:\M3_Outlook"
if (!(Test-Path $destDir)) {
    New-Item -Path $destDir -ItemType Directory
} else {}

$file_patch = Get-ChildItem 'C:\M3_Outlook' | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} |
              select -Last 1 | % { $_.FullName }
$name = Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern name
$email = Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern email
$subject=Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern subject
$attachment = Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern attachment
$Signature = Get-Content ($env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm")
$rname = $name -replace ".*:"
$remail = $email -replace ".*:"
$rsubject = $subject -replace ".*:"
$rattachment = $attachment -replace ".*attachment:"
$rattachment
$sname = $rname -split ";"
$semail = $remail -split ";"
$ssubject = $rsubject -split ";"
$sattachment = $rattachment -split ";"
$body = Get-Content C:\M3_Outlook\PPS200.txt
$Signature = Get-Content ($env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm")
$sRecipientAddr = $semail
$sMsgSubject = $ssubject
$oOutlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
$oMapiNs = $oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$oMailMsg = $oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
$oMailMsg.GetInspector.Activate()
$sSignature = $oMailMsg.HTMLBody
$sSignature = $oMailMsg.HTMLBody
$sattachment | ForEach-Object { $oMailMsg.Attachments.Add($_) }
$oMailMsg.TO = $semail
$oMailMsg.Subject = $sMsgSubject
$oMailMsg.HTMLBody = $body + $sSignature
```

Anyone know what could be the reason for such an action and how to fix it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're facing. What part of your code doesn't work, and how exactly does it "not work", i.e. what are the desired and actual results?

Answer (score 2):

It problem probably comes from the fact that `$body` need a string that `Get-Content C:\M3_Outlook\PPS200.txt` return a collection of strings.

You should test the following, it allow you to load multi-line text file into a single string :

```
$body = Get-Content C:\M3_Outlook\PPS200.txt -raw
```

For me the easiest way is to write the text file using HTML.

Comment: It works great
That was exactly what it was.
Thank you very much

Comment: So You can put the question as answered ?